Why this MOSFET gate driver does not sense the source pins of the MOSFET?
I am looking at the LT1910 High Side MOSFET Driver. It looks weird to me that it does not sense the source voltage of the MOSFET it switches.

Examples of MOSFET gate drives that sense the source pin:
Other MOSFET gate drivers sense the source pin. Their datasheets mention that the source voltage is sensed so they drive the gate with a Vgs of +15 V or +12 V, depending on the driver.
MIC5014/5 Driver senses the source pin:

2ED2734S01GXTMA1 Gate driver, it senses the source pin as well:

My knowledge on the topic is:
A. I suppose the purpose of sensing the voltage at the source is to not violate the Vgs threshold.
B. In any case, if the +15 V or +12 V pumped voltage (depending on the IC) violates the Vgs threshold, it's possible to use an external Zener/TVS between gate and source to clamp the actual voltage to the voltage limit.
Questions:

Why would the LT1910 not sense the source pin and, by default, protect the MOSFET from a Vgs voltage violation? Maybe on high-side driving the MOSFETs this is not an actual concern? (because its datasheet recommends using a Zener when driving a low-side MOSFET):


So is sensing the source to prevent Vgs violation only applicable for low-side driving? After all, when a high-side MOSFET is turned completely on, the source voltage will be the same as the drain.



The gate charge pump is relative to the supply rail, so there's no need to reference the source pin. Since it is intended only for the source-follower configuration, no further protection for excessive \$V_{GS}\$ is required.

LT1910 generates a gate voltage (w.r.t. GND) of ~12V higher than its supply voltage. The elevation amount is lower for supply voltages lower than 12V but still it's almost constant. So, it doesn't need the source pin connection.
MIC5014 internally limits/clamps the gate-to-source voltage to 15V whilst LT1910 doesn't. So it requires the source pin connection. As per the datasheet, the gate is pumped by 4 to 17 V above the supply rail.
2ED2734S01 is a bootstrap high- and low-side driver. By its nature it requires the source pin connection for the high-side in order to get the bootstrap working.
